# como actualizar en mysql un arreglo recibido en php por ajax

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

tengo problemas al querer realizar un update en php, **puedo ver cada elemento del arreglo al recibirlo en $_POST** pero al momento de ejecutar el update no realiza nada, no se.. si es error de sintaxis o que problema se esta generando, aquí les comparto mi código en php.

```
<?php
include_once 'bin/conn.php'; //DATOS DE CONEXION    
$ids = $_POST["id_nota"];
for ($i=0; $i<count($ids); $i++)
{

    $upd= "UPDATE notas SET estado = 'CA', actualizacion=NOW() WHERE id_nota='"$ids[$i]."";
    $mysqli->query($upd);
    //echo $ids[$i]. "<br>";Imprime cada elemento por salto de linea
    echo "Datos Enviados";
}

?>
```

Comment: Bienvenida a Stackoverflow. ¿Qué es `$ids`?  ¿Es un arreglo simple de números, que serían los ids por los que quieres filtrar? ¿Y en la base de datos, la columna `id_nota` de qué tipo es? Si es numérica y `$ids` es un arreglo simple, puedes eliminar el bulce y escribir la consulta con `IN`, sacando los ids con un `implode`. Por ejemplo: **`$ids=implode(",",$_POST["id_nota"]); $upd= "UPDATE notas SET estado = 'CA', actualizacion=NOW() WHERE id_nota IN($ids);` $mysqli->query($upd);`** Eso es todo, **por ahora**, porque tu consulta debe ser mejorada en cuanto a seguridad y en cuanto a lógica.

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder A.Cedano, he realizado una sentencia preparada como se indica en un tema de aquí mismo **¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?** y funciono correctamente.

Comment: De nada. Si quieres pon como respuesta el código implementado y así podría servir a otros usuarios que enfrenten un problema similar en el futuro. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Les comparto mi soluciòn a mi problema por si llegasen a estar en la misma situaciòn, en este caso realice una sentencia preparada, tema que encontre aqui mismo **¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?**

```
<?php

$mysqli=new mysqli("**host o ip**", "**usuario**", "**contraseña**", "**base_de_datos**");

foreach($_POST["id_nota"] as $id) //id_nota es el nombre de mi diccionario nombrado en el ajax con este ciclo iterare en cada elemento del mismo.
    {

        //echo $id. "<br>";
        $upd= $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE notas SET estado = 'CA', actualizacion=NOW() WHERE id_nota=?");//creo la sentencia a ejecutar, en mi caso un UPDATE
        $upd ->bind_param("i", $id);//la "i" es por los datos que enviare en este caso son numeros, si fuesen letras se coloca una "s"
        $upd->execute();//se ejecuta la sentencia
        echo "Datos enviados";//imprimo en pantalla que se ejecuto la accion
    }
```

Como mencione arriba,